# How do I manage a Python based daemon on Linux?

Tags: python, linux, bash, daemon, init.d

I have a working Python based program that I want to run as a daemon. Currently I'm doing it in a very hackish manner of starting it in with [`screen`](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/)`-d -m name` session and killing it with `pkill -9 -f name`.

Eventually I'm doing to have to move this to the better system we use here (thus **I'm not willing to modify the program**) but in the interim, I'm looking for a cleaner way to do this.

My current thinking is kick it off as a background task from an inti.d script but how do I write the part to bring it back down?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [**PEP 3143 -- Standard daemon process library**](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3143/)

Answer (score 6):

On linux there is a [start-stop-daemon](http://linuxreviews.org/man/start-stop-daemon/) utility as part of the init.d tools.

It is very flexible and allows different ways for capturing the pid of your server.

There is also a file /etc/init.d/skeleton  which can serve as a basis for your own init.d script.

If your target platform is debian based, it makes sense to create a debina package to deploy it as it also helps getting a daemon properly integrated in the rest of the system. And it is not too complicated (if you have done it ten times before ;-)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do it with code in python, this is a pretty standard C-method that was ported to python that I use.  It works flawlessly, and you can even choose a file output.

```
import os
import signal
def daemonize(workingdir='.', umask=0,outfile='/dev/null'):
#Put in background
pid = os.fork()
if pid == 0:
    #First child
    os.setsid()
    pid = os.fork() #fork again
    if pid == 0:
        os.chdir(workingdir)
        os.umask(umask)
    else:
        os._exit(0)
else:
    os._exit(0)

#Close all open resources
try:
    os.close(0)
    os.close(1)
    os.close(2)
except:
    raise Exception("Unable to close standard output. Try running with 'nodaemon'")
    os._exit(1)

#Redirect output
os.open(outfile, os.O_RDWR | os.O_CREAT)
os.dup2(0,1)
os.dup2(0,2)
```

Then, you can use signals to catch when a kill-signal was sent to the program and exit nicely.  Example from [Python Docs](http://docs.python.org/library/signal.html)

```
import signal, os

def handler(signum, frame):
    print 'Signal handler called with signal', signum
    raise IOError("Couldn't open device!")

# Set the signal handler and a 5-second alarm
signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, handler)
signal.alarm(5)

# This open() may hang indefinitely
fd = os.open('/dev/ttyS0', os.O_RDWR)

signal.alarm(0)          # Disable the alarm
```

Answer (score 2):

There are modules that could be used to daemonize a python script.

[python-daemon](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon) implements the well-behaved daemon specification (PEP 3143).

Also [this module](https://github.com/kasun/YapDi) recently came up on github which seems more pythonic and easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

Starting it with an `init.d` style script is a good way. You take it down with POSIX Signals ... See [StackOverflow, Signal handling in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163194/signal-handling-in-python).

Comment: I can `kill -9` it for all I care, but I don't know how to reliably find its PID.

Comment: @BCS: `-9` is often ... *overkill* (pardon the pun). See [kill -9](http://speculation.org/garrick/kill-9.html). As for finding its PID, your script can create a pidfile in `/var/run` or use a lib that allows you to set `argv[0]` to some easily identified name for use with `pkill`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473620/how-do-you-create-a-daemon-in-python) or more exactly accepted solution.

Comment: I'd really rather not muck with the internals of the program. Heck I'd rather keep what I'm using now rather than do that.

Comment: Really you don't need to change your program, if it is importable. Joust import your main in deamon-example Run method, 
(replace while loop).